# What does "-R 120 -d 0 -e 0" does in command "/usr/bin/yum -y -R 120 -d 0 -e 0 update yum" command?

Tags: linux, yum

What does `-R 120 -d 0 -e 0` does in command `/usr/bin/yum -y -R 120 -d 0 -e 0 update yum` command?

I am trying to run this command in bash script for a tutorial. I wanted to understand what does `-R 120 -d 0 -e 0` does in yum command.

Comment: Other than exactly what the man page describes them as doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of all options is written in the manpage:

```
-R, --randomwait=[time in minutes]
    Sets the maximum amount of time yum will wait before performing a command - 
    it randomizes over the time. 

-d, --debuglevel=[number]
    Sets the debugging level to [number] - turns up or down the amount of things 
    that are printed. Practical range: 0 - 10

-e, --errorlevel=[number]
    Sets the error level to [number] Practical range 0 - 10. 0 means print only critical 
    errors about which you must be told. 1 means print all errors, even ones that are 
    not overly important. 1+ means print more errors (if any) -e 0 is good for cron jobs.
```

So `/usr/bin/yum -y -R 120 -d 0 -e 0 update yum` updates the `yum` package after randomly waiting up to 2 hours, printing only critical errors.